# Bigquery SQL SELECT WHERE field contains many words from other table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of student info with full names, and a list of first names.

```
full_names               first_names  
---------------         -------------
john adam smith          john
jane anna doe            jane
michael brown            bob
```

I want to select the students whose full names contain ANY of a *long* list of first names. For example, `John Adam Smith` contains the word `john`, I want to select that row. `Michael Brown` doesn't match any of names so I don't want it.

I could do this but it's *crazy inefficient* typing 300+ names.

```
SELECT names
FROM full_names
WHERE names CONTAIN 'john' 
  OR names CONTAIN 'jane'
  OR names CONTAIN 'bob'
...
(300 more rows)
```

**What I've tried** - Made the list of names into a second table `first_names`, and tried to select names from the first table that were in the second.

```
SELECT names
FROM full_names 
WHERE names CONTAINS 
    (SELECT names
    FROM first_names);
```

However, I get the error:

`Error: ELEMENT can only be applied to result with 0 or 1 row.`

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT full_name
FROM `project.dataset.full_names` a
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.first_names` b 
GROUP BY full_name
HAVING MAX(REGEXP_CONTAINS(full_name, name))
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your questions as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `full_names` AS (
  SELECT 'john adam smith' full_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jane anna doe' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'michael brown' 
), `first_names` AS (
  SELECT 'john' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jane' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bob' 
)
SELECT full_name
FROM `full_names` a
CROSS JOIN `first_names` b 
GROUP BY full_name
HAVING MAX(REGEXP_CONTAINS(full_name, name))
```

result is

```sql
full_name    
---------
john adam smith  
jane anna doe
```

> More options:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT full_name
FROM `project.dataset.full_names` a
JOIN `project.dataset.first_names` b 
ON full_name LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

> OR

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT full_name
FROM `project.dataset.full_names`, UNNEST(SPLIT(full_name, ' ')) part
JOIN `project.dataset.first_names` 
ON part = name
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! The samples work fine and I appreciate your thorough explanation. Unfortunately it can't seem to run on my full dataset as I have to upgrade my payment Tier first. If it's not too much trouble, is there any way to make this query smaller? Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: what exactly problem you have? any error message? please clarify. Billing depends on how much data is involved in query - so you should use ONLY columns you need to use to minimize cost

Comment: "Error: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 2006 or higher required." -- I have 300 first names and 27 million full names. I still have $300 credits left in my BQ free tier so I'm not sure why this query is not going through. Edit: Yes, am already only using columns I need to minimise cost.

Comment: Try option with LIKE instead of REGEXP_CONTAINS. let me know if still `resources exceeded ...` error

Comment: no prob, and thank you for being the bigquery hero on this site. you've previously answered another questions of mine actually. thank you!

Comment: Added one more option - hope this can help in fighting with `resources exceeded ...` error as it even eliminates use of `LIKE` - please share your results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160047/discussion-between-angsty-robot-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
SELECT names
FROM 
full_names a
inner join
first_names b
on a.names like CONCAT('%', b.names, '%') ;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me rows like "john" but leaves out rows like "john adam smith". I also want to include rows that partially match the target, not just those that *fully* match the target.

Comment: @angsty_robot now try!

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try this: The column names are according to the columns in the snapshot

```
 Select * from full_names
    where  first_names IN
    ( Select full_names from full_names)
```